# Weighted Average for only items with the same code?

Tags: excel-formula

I have two tables, `Products` and `Ingredients`. I want to take a the weighted average of all `Products` with the same `Code`.

Here is the Ingredient Table

[image: Ingredient Table]

And Here is the Product table where I am using a formula to calculate `Avg Price`.

[image: Product Table]

Here is a formula that I used but I have no idea how to change it to only calculate the averages for items with the same code. I thought about AVERAGEIFS but not sure how to implement it into the formula.

```
=B2 * SUMPRODUCT(Ingredient!D1:D6, Ingredient!C1:C6)/SUM(Ingredient!C1:C6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
= B2 * SUM( Ingredient!$C$2:$C$6 * Ingredient!$D$2:$D$6 * (Ingredient!$B$2:$B$6=C2) )
     / SUM( Ingredient!$C$2:$C$6 * (Ingredient!$B$2:$B$6=C2) )
```

Comment: Realized when I tested it that it was not giving true weighted average - fixed it.